# How to read Excel cell value?

Tags: c#, excel

Looking for help on how to read a few cell values from Excel.  I thought I'd start with one.

```
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,    Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
var cell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1];
```

Though I am having no luck.  I want to be able to read the value of the cell and store it somewhere, and then have it check every few seconds for the value.

Comment: what are you getting thus far with the code sample you have posted..? can you provide a bit more debugging Info

Answer (score 1):

You seriously want to take a look at EPPLus:
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It's available from NuGet for usage in your projects. It's by far the most easy and clean way of interfacing between C# and an excel document. It's also free, btw.

Tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in#1

```
private DataTable WorksheetToDataTable(ExcelWorksheet oSheet)
{
int totalRows = oSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
int totalCols = oSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
DataTable dt = new DataTable(oSheet.Name);
DataRow dr = null;
for (int i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
{
    if (i > 1) dr = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            dt.Columns.Add(oSheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
        else
            dr[j - 1] = oSheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
return dt;
```

}

This reads all the columns and rows in EPPLus.

Comment: In EPPLus, or in Excel?  How could I alter this read a specific five cells?

I don't want to store it in a dataTable though.  Would rather store it as a variable that my program is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Worksheet sheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"] as Worksheet;
Range rng = sheet.Cells[1,1] as Range;
object value = rng.Value;
```

...should do what you want. Try this and if you get any errors let me know.

The value will either be a `string`, `double`, `DateTime`, `bool` or `int` value.

Aside from the `int`s, these are quite self-explanatory. The `int` values represent the different error codes that are possible, e.g. `#VALUE!`

(Incidentally, rather than referencing the Excel PIA, I would recommend usingn NetOffice, which is available free via NuGet, to reference the Excel object model. Advantage being that you are not tied to a specific version of Excel when you deploy)

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the `.Value` or `.Value2` property of the cell:

```
if (cell.Value2 == null)
    // cell is blank
else if(cell.Value2 is string)
    // cell is text
else if (cell.Value is double)
    // cell is number;
else if (cell.Value2 is double)
    // cell is date
```

Note the last two `if`'s. `.Value2` will return a double for both numbers and dates, but `.Value` will return a double only for numbers. The order that you check is important.