# C# Open an excel spreadsheet and read the header column into a string

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am fairly new using Excel spreadsheet in `C#`. I want to be able to open an excel spread sheet and then read the Header column and save it to a string.

e.g. if my headers are Name, Address, City, State in the Excel spreadsheet

I want the output in a string result = "Name, Address, City, State"

Comment: use EPPLUS library. [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763766/how-to-read-excel-cell-value)

Comment: @Alex that's just 1 of many options, the OP needs to show a little bit more effort in regards to, how to read / parse excel spreadsheet or .CSV file

Comment: part of the reason why people are asking you to try it on your own first, and then post a specific problem you are having, is that is the way for responders to asses your level of knowledge (in c#) and steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous libraries out there for parsing Office Documents, but your best bet is to use the OpenXml library as it is both Free and supported by Microsoft:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Here is a tutorial for using the library to read Cells in Excel:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx

Comment: And how to do it then?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the SpreadsheetLight library (http://spreadsheetlight.com/). There are other libraries out there as well, and I would recommend investigating those as well. But I have used SpreadsheetLight on numerous occasions, and it seems to be reliable. It's free and simple. You can do something like this:

```
        SLDocument sl = new SLDocument("ExistingSpreadsheet.xlsx", "Sheet1");
        var name = sl.GetCellValueAsString("A1");
        var address = sl.GetCellValueAsString("B1");
        var city = sl.GetCellValueAsString("C1");
        var state = sl.GetCellValueAsString("D1");
        var result = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", name, address, city, state);
```